# Upgrade web application in oracle apex 18.1

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an application that I developed. But I had to update it. I made a copy of this application (so that the original continues to work). I made the necessary edits and tested everything. And now I want to update all these edits in the original. I can do it so as not to update everything manually (because there are a lot of cute edits) because it's very long ???. id of the original application is 101, and my copies are 104. I thought I'd just change these id, but it's impossible. I have an error. I will be grateful for the help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

1. Take an application export of 101, as a backup.
2. Delete application 101
3. Copy application 104 and make the new ID 101.